# Trapping command line parameters from C# code

Tags: c#-3.0

Suppose I have typed `excel.exe /r "c:\book1.xlsx"` in the *Run Window*.

How will I `trap the switch(/r) and the parameter "c:\book1.xlsx" from my C# code`?

Thanks

Comment: Is your C# code running inside Excel?

Comment: Yes that's true.. it is a template(Excel 2007) project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If your code is running in-process (in excel.exe)**

You can get the command-line via the [`Environment.CommandLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline.aspx) property.  Note that a process *can* change it's own command-line (it's just some bytes in memory, after all), but this is not often done.

**If your code is running out-of-process (option 1, recommended)**

You can use WMI to get another process' command-line arguments.  See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/8efe163b-927e-4895-9983-b8c47b515d7c/).  You'll need to add a reference to System.Management.dll.  For example:

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='{0}'", "excel.exe");

using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
{
    foreach (ManagementObject process in searcher.Get())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(process["CommandLine"]);
    }
}
```

This will print the command lines of all running instances of excel.exe.  You can also query by process ID by using the `ProcessId` parameter in place of the `Name` parameter in the query.

**If your code is running out-of-process (option 2, trickier)**

You can also get a remote process' command-line by using `NtQueryInformationProcess` and [`ReadProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553(VS.85).aspx) to read in the process environment block (PEB) to get to the `_RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` which contains the command-line.  None of this stuff is documented, however, which means that it's unsupported and subject to change.  The details of doing this are outlined [here](http://wj32.wordpress.com/2009/01/24/howto-get-the-command-line-of-processes/).

Answer (score 0):

Command line parameters without options

Example: yourExecutable.exe parameter1 parameter2 parameter3

Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28VS.71%29.aspx

Command line parameters with options - There are no standard parsers available. You either need to write your own or *borrow*

Example: yourExecutable.exe -f fileName --create

Refer: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/command_line.aspx